# How to join the content of a nested list with out losing the sublists?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have the following nested list of strings:

```
my_list = [['Yesterday I was talking to a friend who is considering applying for a job here at Tailwind.', 'He asked me why I took the job of Director of Marketing and Growth back in July, and among the many things I told him was this….'], ['Nearly every day somebody from Tailwind’s product development team talks at considerable length with one of our members, all of these conversations get written up, shared with the whole team on Slack (our instant messaging system), and they help us decide what features to build.', 'Around the office we call these “cust dev calls”, short for customer development calls, and they’re constant.'], ['Why fight over what you think customers want?'], ['My friend was impressed.', 'At his last job decisions about what features to build were considered too important to be made by anybody but the CEO, based on his considerable knowledge of the market.', 'In fact that was one of my friend’s biggest frustrations working there – that his ideas were never taken very seriously because his CEO always knew better than he did.',  'Or he thought he knew better.',  'The product my friend built there hasn’t found success yet.'], ['Of course there are a group of people who know what your customers want even better than you or your well-informed CEO do, and those people are your customers.','So why not cut out the middleman, ask them what their biggest frustrations are, see what ideas they have to solve them; think carefully about the best product you could build to overcome those frustrations, and then build what it is your customer really want.']]
```

I would like to split into a single element list the sublists of `my_list`, something like (*):

```
[['Yesterday I was talking to a friend who is considering applying for a job here at Tailwind. He asked me why I took the job of Director of Marketing and Growth back in July, and among the many things I told him was this….'], ['Nearly every day somebody from Tailwind’s product development team talks at considerable length with one of our members, all of these conversations get written up, shared with the whole team on Slack (our instant messaging system), and they help us decide what features to build. Around the office we call these “cust dev calls”, short for customer development calls, and they’re constant.'], ['Why fight over what you think customers want?'], ['My friend was impressed. At his last job decisions about what features to build were considered too important to be made by anybody but the CEO, based on his considerable knowledge of the market. In fact that was one of my friend’s biggest frustrations working there – that his ideas were never taken very seriously because his CEO always knew better than he did. Or he thought he knew better. The product my friend built there hasn’t found success yet.'], ['Of course there are a group of people who know what your customers want even better than you or your well-informed CEO do, and those people are your customers. So why not cut out the middleman, ask them what their biggest frustrations are, see what ideas they have to solve them; think carefully about the best product you could build to overcome those frustrations, and then build what it is your customer really want.']]
```

I know that in order to merge all the elements of each sublist of `my_list` you can do:

```
my_list.join('')
```

So I tried to:

```
' '.join(itertools.chain(*my_list))
```

However I lost the sublists. Any idea of which is the fastest way to get (*)

Comment: Are you sure you want a list of one-element lists, rather than a list of strings? It doesn't look to me like the problem is "losing the sublists"; it looks like the problem is that all strings in all sublists are getting joined into a single string, instead of separate sublists getting joined separately.

Comment: Thanks for the help @user2357112!. Yes, I am actually trying to have everything into a single string separated by spaces insted of "elements"

Comment: "I am actually trying to have everything into a single string" - that's the opposite of what you said in the question.

Comment: the question could be improved by not pasting the super-long example but just a smaller example, like the ones used in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create 1 string from sublists using `join`, but store it in a single item `list`:

```
[[' '.join(x)] for x in my_list]
```

set `my_list = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"],["e","f"]]`, the result is

```
[['a b'], ['c d'], ['e f']]
```

however, it's not really useful to create sublists with one elements (unless you want to add elements later). You could simplify it with:

```
[' '.join(x) for x in my_list]
```

you would get:

```
['a b', 'c d', 'e f']
```

Comment: Well I was confused and actually it is useful since I am wrangling some documents. Thanks!

Comment: a map would require you to do `list(map(lambda x: [" ".join(x)],my_list))`: a lambda and a list conversion in python 3 since map returns an iterator now: less readable. list comprehensions are really optimized, so it's about the fastest way unless some specialized pre-compiled packages does the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> my_list = [["one", "two"], ["three", "four"]]
>>> [[' '.join(x)] for x in my_list]
[['one two'], ['three four']]
>>> map(lambda x: [' '.join(x)], my_list)
[['one two'], ['three four']]
```

Two approaches

Comment: Thanks for the help!.  The desired output should be: `[['one two'], ['three four']]`

Comment: Edited—how does that look?

Comment: Using the generator is the most Pythonesque, but you won't know which is fastest until you time it.

Comment: careful: with python 3 you have to convert your `map` to a `list` else you get an iterator. Which makes `map` & `filter` really less interesting in python 3. List comprehensions are the way.